# XML file reader in java

Tags: java, xml, file, windowbuilder

I'm trying to create a xml file reader. I've made the main xml file using eclipse within a JFrame and written the file reader code as below;

```
public xml() {
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 486, 533);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

JButton btnopen = new JButton("Open");
btnopen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(contentPane);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
try
{
File file = fc.getSelected();
textFirst.setText(file.getAbsolute("XML", "xml"));

StaxParser read = new StaxParser();
List<Student> readStudents = read.readStudents(file.getAbsolutePath());
for (Student student : readStudents) {
textOutput.append(student+"\n\n");
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
//TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
textOutput.append("\nError");
}
} else {
textOutput.setText("user cancelled operation");
}
}
});
```

I'm getting an error on the bit where it says;

```
File file = fc.getSelected();
```

The error I'm getting is this;

```
http://gyazo.com/10d739192c178e04a085bd392e93139b
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are trying to build an XML reader? Because there are a ton of different ones suited for various needs already out there.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Yes in fact there is... It's for my course assignment. Why would I ask on here for guidance on my current code for the xml reader if I was able to just use one of the many xml readers off the internet?

Comment: So what's the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exception in link, you are missing some imports, e.g.:

`File cannot be resolved to a type` is missing

```
import java.io.File;
```

`List cannot be resolved to a type` is missing

```
import java.util.List;
```

etc.
Try to add correct import for all classes mentioned in that exception.

And, as @Gaurav Joseph mentioned, you are using wrong method to get file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it wrong try

```
File file = fc.getSelectedFile()
```

Comment: I've made this change to my code now I'm getting an error on the line public static void main(String[] args) { even though there is no red x next to that line of the code, heck there isn't anything even wrong with that line of the code. @Gaurav

Comment: Yes there was there is no method called getSelected refer this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html as for the rest of the errors use imports `import java.io.File;` and `import java.util.List;` also import the Student class code from wherever you have put it.